# PyVis - search Node

Tags: python, pyvis

I am using PyVis to build a graph (essentially a call chain). So I like how it generates a html file, with related code, to visualize it.

Is there a way I can generate a 'Search node" functionality ? The Graph I am loading is huge, and a function to zoom in to a node of interest, is what I am looking for...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you find a sufficient solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is a filter function in PyVis. 
When creating the network instance, set **filer_menu** parameter to True.
And there is search menu shown in html file.

```
g = Network('1200px', width="100%", notebook=True, directed=True, filter_menu=True)
```

reference from https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#edges